# CIFS share can no longer mount

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I used to have a CIFS share pointing to a Windows machine's C drive, however it broke some time ago (I assume following an update, but I don't use the share all that often, so I don't know exactly how long it was broke).

I have an automount file setup, but it fails to mount, and manual mounting fails as well.

```
$ sudo mount -a
[sudo] password for root: 
Couldn't chdir to /Windows: No such device
```

```
$ cat /etc/fstab
# Static information about the filesystems.
# See fstab(5) for details.
    
# <file system> <dir> <type> <options> <dump> <pass>
# /dev/nvme0n1p1
UUID=8ef5a797-97ec-4a83-a5be-35b664574f62   /           ext4        rw,relatime 0 1
    
# /dev/nvme0n1p2
UUID=a7947fd4-a876-49f2-be3a-c93b57de8e7f   none        swap        defaults    0 0
    
# 192.168.1.10:/cygdrive/c  /windows    nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,noexec,nosuid
//10.0.0.10/c   /Windows    cifs    credentials=/home/terminus/.cifs_creds
```

```
$ sudo cat .cifs_creds
username=ExampleUser
password=ExamplePassword
```

```
$ sudo cat /etc/systemd/system/Windows.automount
[Unit]
Description=Gaming rig C: share
    
[Mount]
What=//10.0.0.10/c
Where=/Windows
Type=cifs
Options=credentials=/home/terminus/.cifs_creds
    
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
$ ping 10.0.0.10
PING 10.0.0.10 (10.0.0.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=0.198 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=2.11 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.10: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.218 ms
^C
--- 10.0.0.10 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2020ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.198/0.842/2.110/0.896 ms
```

Comment: Either the local directory /Windows does not exist, the source system does not exist on IP address 10.0.0.10, or you have not shared the c drive as `c`, since it would normally be as `c$` if I remember correctly.

Comment: run `net share` on the windows box to make sure you see the share. verify that the files in the share are (to the extent you want) readable by ExampleUser. Note that share permissions overlay on top of disk permissions, so allowing read on the share, but not allowing it on the underlying files and directories will still give you Access Denied. what errors do you see if you try to mount the share interactively?

Comment: @Bib
`ls / | grep Window` returns "Windows"

`ipconfig` returns (amongst other stuff) "IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.0.0.10"

and as for the last bit, which @FrankThomas also asked about, `net share` returns both a "C$           C:\                             Default share" as well as "C            C:\                             BenPC C Drive"

ExampleUser also has full permissions to the C share.

Comment: Do you have the cifs kernel module loaded? Does the account which you are using to connect, have permissions to C:\BenPC? Test it, don't just assume it is correct.